# Firebase storage java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

When the application starts, 500 pictures should be downloaded.
But after ~120 requests `isLandRef.getFile(file);` i have got a error like this: `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8@800c85 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@e340ada[Running, pool size = 3, active threads = 3, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 0]`
And after this error images are no longer downloaded.
I was able to solve this error by adding `Thread.sleep (100);`, but because of this my application freezes up.
How to solve the error problem without using `Thread.sleep (100);`?

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if (data.getCount() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.getCount(); i++) {
            data.moveToPosition(i);
            loadImage(data.getString(data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ExamContract.QuestionEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE)));
        }
        finish();
    }
}

private void loadImage(String image) {
    StorageReference isLandRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images/" + image + ".jpg");
    try {
        File path = getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File file = new File(path, image + ".jpg");
        try {
            isLandRef.getFile(file);

        } catch (RejectedExecutionException r) {
            r.printStackTrace();
            Thread.sleep(100);
            try {
                isLandRef.getFile(file);
            } catch (RejectedExecutionException j) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                isLandRef.getFile(file);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Can you give me some feedback if you managed to fix this and how?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a maximum queue size.  Instead of queueing all your jobs at the beginning, you should either only get what you need now, or write your own queue and continue to feed their queue as each job finishes.